# Issue in saving data to cassandra using Spring's ReactiveCrudRepository

Tags: java, spring-data-cassandra, reactive

I am trying to save data to cassandra using ReactiveCrudRepository in a WebApp using spring boot.

I am getting the following error :

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is reactor.core.Exceptions$BubblingException: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Scheduler unavailable

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:986) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:206) ~[websocket-server-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at orderfulfilment.filters.OAuth2Filter.doFilter(OAuth2Filter.java:47) ~[classes/:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) ~[jetty-server-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548) ~[jetty-security-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) ~[jetty-server-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190) ~[jetty-server-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595) ~[jetty-server-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188) ~[jetty-server-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253) ~[jetty-server-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168) ~[jetty-server-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564) ~[jetty-server-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166) ~[jetty-server-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155) ~[jetty-server-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) ~[jetty-server-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) ~[jetty-server-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564) ~[jetty-server-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:317) ~[jetty-server-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251) [jetty-server-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279) [jetty-io-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110) [jetty-io-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124) [jetty-io-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable.invokePreferred(Invocable.java:128) [jetty-util-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable$InvocableExecutor.invoke(Invocable.java:222) [jetty-util-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:294) [jetty-util-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:126) [jetty-util-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:673) ~[jetty-util-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:591) ~[jetty-util-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
```

I am trying to save in the following way :

```
Person x = new Person();
x.setFirstname("ABC");
x.setLastname("DEF");
x.setAge(30);
//Way 1 - failed
persistentService.save(x).publishOn(Schedulers.elastic()).subscribe(p -> log.info(p.getFirstname()), e -> log.error("failed", e));
//Way 2 - failed
persistentService.save(x).then().block();
//Way 3 - failed
persistentService.save(x).block();
```

There is no problem in connecting to cassandra. I am succesfully able to connect and the table schema is also getting creating on it's own through the spring data libraries.
Following is how my PersistentService looks like [which is autowired in the controller from where I am trying to persist the Person object] :

```
@Repository
public interface PersistentService extends ReactiveCassandraRepository<Person, String>{

}
```

I am using the following dependencies to achieve this :

- spring-boot-starter-parent - 2.0.0.M3
- spring - 5.0.0.RC3
- spring-data-releasetrain - Kay-RC2
- reactor-core - 3.1.0.M3
- spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra - 2.0.0.M3

Comment: Do you have somewhere a reproducible sample (Github repo or such)?

Comment: I created a new project to reproduce the issue, but somehow (ironically) it is not at all reproducible there. It is working just fine and saves the data to cassandra.
https://gitlab.com/mayankmishra93/cassandra-reactive-demo .... trying further to reproduce it as it is happening in the original project.

Comment: You might want to enable debug mode to see more details about the exception.